# Is it possible to run Visual Studio 2008 on a mini laptop?

Tags: laptop, visual-studio-2008

Is it possible to run Visual Studio 2008 on a mini laptop?

- Procesor: Intel® Atom N270 1.6GHz
- Memory: 1GB DDR2
- HD: 160GB SATA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely possible. I've run it on a netbook before, and even though it wasn't exactly the *fastest* experience I've had with Visual Studio, it wasn't really bad at all. The Intellisense is still very responsive, and unless you're compiling huge projects, the Atom is quite capable of keeping up!

The only downsides I really noticed are the smaller screen (obviously) as I am used to coding on multiple large displays, and the smaller keyboard which takes some getting used to if you're coding on it.

Here are the [Hardware Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c26cc39%28VS.80%29.aspx) if you're interested, your netbook is more than capable.

Comment: Usability concerns are things people tend to leave out, good thing you pointed that out -- the small cramptastic keyboard and small resolution screen made it less then ideal for actual use for coding.

Personally, 1024x600 was too small for me, 1366x768 and 1280x800 are probably a bit more comfortable.  So I'd suggest at least a 10" machine or larger -- those tend to have roomier keyboards and the slightly bigger resolutions.

Comment: I would hate to spend serious time on a project with just the standard keyboard and small resolution of a netbook. External keyboard and a monitor would make this much more bearable.

Comment: i do not sense if that is going to be his _primary_ development workstation, but rather something light and mobile he can take to places he wouldn't want to lug a heavy laptop to. i also install VS 2008/2010 on my tablet netbook, but that is only for occasional light development activities i'd wanna try out when outside with only my tablet.